# Yii2 Custom validation problem with Php 7

Tags: php, validation, yii2, php-7

I am using PHP version 5.6.25 with Yii2 version 2.0.15.1 and working fine with custom validation, as i change my php version to 7.0.10 the model gives following error

```
{"name":"PHP Notice","message":"Array to string conversion","code":8,"type":"yii\\base\\ErrorException","file":"D:\\wamp\\www\\cfms-hc\\models\\CASES.php","line":210,"stack-trace":["#0 D:\\wamp\\www\\cfms-hc\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\validators\\InlineValidator.php(72): ::call_user_func:{D:\\wamp\\www\\cfms-hc\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\validators\\InlineValidator.php:72}()","#1 D:\\wamp\\www\\cfms-hc\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\validators\\Validator.php(267): yii\\validators\\InlineValidator->validateAttribute()","#2 D:\\wamp\\www\\cfms-hc\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Model.php(367): yii\\validators\\Validator->validateAttributes()
```

My validation function is following.

```
public function validateInstitutiondate($attribute,$params)
{
        $institutiondate = date('Y', strtotime($this->$attribute));
        //$institutiondate = $this->$attribute ;
        $caseyear = $this->$params['CASEYEAR'];
    //$aa = $params['CASEYEAR'];
    //$caseyear = $this->$params->CASEYEAR;
    if ($institutiondate != $caseyear) {

        $this->addError($attribute, 'Institution date must be of same year.'.$caseyear);
        //$this->addError($this, $attribute, '{attribute} must be of same year.');
        return false;

    }

}
```

and validating using following line.

```
 ['INSTITUTIONDATE','validateInstitutiondate','params'=>['CASEYEAR'=>'CASEYEAR']],
```

Comment: add your complete `Cases` Model in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to change in precedence of indirect properties introduced in PHP 7.0. In PHP 5 `$this->$params['CASEYEAR']` is treated as `$this->{$params['CASEYEAR']}`, but in PHP 7 it is treated as `$this->{$params}['CASEYEAR']`. You need to use `{}` to specify how expression should be treated:

```
$caseyear = $this->{$params['CASEYEAR']};
```

See [upgrade notes about this change](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect).